# Python - Searching though Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search, tuples

For this problem, I want to search through the tuple and **find all states that start with 'N' and insert it to a new list.**

I attempted the problem and got stuck. Can anyone help me out? Thank you

```
states = ("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "FL", "GA", 
          "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", 
          "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
          "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", 
          "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY")

letterN = "N"
listN=[]

for i in states:
    if i == letterN:
       listN.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listN=[st for st in states if st.startswith('N')]

> output: ['NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function instead of a script:

```
def find_n_states(states, letter):
    n_states = []
    for state in states:
        if state[0] == letter:
            n_states.append(state)
    return n_states
```

```
find_n_states(states, 'N')

Output: ['NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND']
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are saying if i == letterN which would always return to false since "N-" does not equal "N". We can use str.startswith(substring) to check if the string starts with the given substring.

```
states = ("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "FL", "GA", 
          "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", 
          "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
          "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", 
          "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY")

letterN = "N"
listN=[]

for i in states:
    if i.startswith(letterN):
       listN.append(i)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of having a variable named `letterN` that only holds the letter `'N'`? just use `'N'` as a string, much shorter, the variable is completely pointless named like that